# crossdomain $.ajax and 404 error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve some data using `$.ajax` from the external ASP.NET MVC site (in this case - from my site). The code below geive me a `404 Not Found error` (of course the `url` is valid.

But, if I change the url from `url: 'http://myurl.com/Home/GetMyCode/?id=mycode'` to `url: 'http://localhost:123/Home/GetMyCode/?id=mycode'` everything is fine. So, how to fix it ?

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurl.com/Home/GetMyCode/?id=mycode',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (res) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ...
        }
    });


    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMyCode(string id)
    {
        try 
        {
            return Json(new { result = "ok", resultData = "OK") });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { result = "error", resultData = "An error occured" });
        }            
    }
```

Comment: is myurl.com accepting web traffic on port 80? if not it needs to be specified within the url. (http://myurl.com:123/Home/GetMyCode/?id=mycode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that tutorial worked for me, I had to implement the JSONP handling in my MVC project.  http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/using-jsonp-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

Answer (score 2):

***Two Methods for Handling Cross-Domain Ajax Calls:***

**JSONP: The Current Standard for Cross-Domain Access**

JSONP is a convention used by some sites to expose their content in a way that makes it easier for callers to consume data via script, even from an external domain. The trick consists in having the site return some JSON content not as a plain string but wrapped up in a script function call. For more details..

- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/04/JSONP-for-crosssite-Callbacks
- http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

**Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)**

To enable cross-domain requests in environments that do not support cors yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc), set  `$.support.cors = true;`
You just tell jQuery that you're in an environment where Cross-Domain XHR requests are possible.

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve data crossdomain, you probably need to use 'jsonp'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a DNS issue. Are you able to get to: http://myurl.com ?

Is the .com domain you are trying to access publicly accessible? Or is it a loopback to localhost?